# ASP.NET AJAX $find always returns null in usercontrol

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I want to use multiple targets with my ModalPopUp extender. One of my buttons is set as target in the ModalPopup and the other one will use server-side code to show the ModalPopup.

This is my ModalPopup so far:

```
<msAjax:ModalPopupExtender ID="modalInform" runat="server" 
        BehaviorID="modalInform" 
        TargetControlID="btnSearchUsers" 
        PopupControlID="pnlInform" 
        RepositionMode="RepositionOnWindowResize" 
        BackgroundCssClass="modalWindow"
        OkControlID="linkCloseInform" />
```

Then I found [this little tutorial](http://www.asp.net/ajax/tutorials/launching-a-modal-popup-window-from-server-code-cs) on the ASP.NET AJAX site.
But when I use $find("modalInform") in the pageLoad Javascript function (as defined in the tutorial at the bottom), I'm always getting a $find("modalInform") is null error.

This code is included in a usercontrol, the usercontrol is used in a ASPX page and this ASPX-page uses a MasterPage.
I've noticed that if I'm using

```
<%= modalInform.ClientID %>
```

I'm getting a different value then defined in my HTML-source (propably because of the MasterPage?).

Does somebody know what the problem could be?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to combine the ClientID with the $find method.

instead of

```
$find("modalInform")
```

try this

```
$find('<%= modalInform.ClientID %>')
```

Comment: What error do you get? Is $find('<%= modalInform.ClientID %>') null or is the function not defined? Do you have Scriptmanager/ScriptmanagerProxy registered?

Comment: Error: $find("ctl00_contentHolder_propDocument_modalInform") is null

I've added a ScriptManager in my MasterPage.

Comment: Is documentGetElementById('<%= modalInform.ClientID %>') null too?

Comment: Sorry, misspelled: document.getElementById('<%= modalInform.ClientID %>').
Is there a difference between the value from $find or document.getElementbyid and the real id in your generated html file?

Comment: It is, the value with document.getElementById is also null! Has this something to do because I'm using this in a usercontrol?

Comment: You havent answered my last question. What is the id in the generated html file? If you're using jQuery you can also find your control with $("[id$=modalInform]")
The ID will change for every control what is inside an NamingContainer(UserControl,Gridview,etc), but ClientID property should take that into account.

Comment: $find and document.getElementById both return null. As a test I've set alert("<%= modalInform.ClientID %>"); and the ID I get here is the same as in my HTML-code...

Comment: That must have something to do with the time your script is executed.
Why cant you just use the Show method of the extender?

Comment: Also having trouble with calling the Show-method... I'll try to extract the ModalPopup to a seperate page. Maybe something is blocking my ModalPopup. Thanks for the quick responses and help!

Comment: Found the problem... somewhere along in the code the OkControl was set to Visible="false"... unbelievable how much time I lost with this. Thanks again Tim!

Answer (score 1):

I tried the below example and I also faced same error like $find was returning null.
Later I realised, I missed the **"BehaviorID="AutoCompleteEx""** attributes.

http://forums.asp.net/t/1323927.aspx

And in the **$find("AutoCompleteEx")** method worked like a charm.